# [Implementing graphs in python]: are lists of connected nodes preferable over dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have an assignment to create a graph/map of nodes.

```
GRAPH = {}

""" ===================================================================
    This function makes a network out of the two nodes
    node1, node2 and puts them in a dictionary: graph
    ---------------------
    node1 : Dictionary
        key: node2 [neighbouring node]
        value: 1
    ---------------------
    node2 : Dictionary
        key: node1 [neighbouring node] 
        value: 1
===================================================================== """
def make_link(graph, node1, node2):
    if node1 not in graph:
        graph[node1] = {}
    (graph[node1])[node2] = 1
    if node2 not in graph:
        graph[node2] = {}
    (graph[node2])[node1] = 1
    return graph

flights = []
flights.append(("LAX","DFW"))
flights.append(("SAE","LAX"))
flights.append(("ORD","LAX"))
flights.append(("ORD","SAE"))

for (x,y) in flights:
    make_link(GRAPH, x, y)

print GRAPH
```

Output:

```
codewingx@CodeLair:~/repo/python/Graphs$ python map.py
{'DFW': {'LAX': 1}, 'LAX': {'DFW': 1, 'ORD': 1, 'SAE': 1}, 'ORD': {'LAX': 1, 'SAE': 1}, 'SAE': {'ORD': 1, 'LAX': 1}}
```

I find it redundant as only the connected nodes are having a value of 1.

Q1. Shouldn't I be using a list of connected nodes instead of the inner dictionaries? 
like:

```
{'DFW': ['LAX'], 'LAX': ['DFW', 'ORD', 'SAE'], 'ORD':['LAX','SAE'],'SAE':['ORD','LAX']}
```

Q2. Should I be adding all nodes and give them a value of 1 when connected else 0?

Comment: As for Q1, unless you are planning to use this with thousands of vertices I don't think it matters (querying for a connectivity between two vertices will be faster using the `dict` because it is basically a hash table). And as for Q2, it is common to represent a graph using a [Adjacency Matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjacencyMatrix.html)

Comment: If I have understood correctly, I should use `dicts` in the form of an adjacency matrix?

Comment: No, if you want to implement an adjacency matrix then use a 2d array

Comment: Style tip: function [docstring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring#Python) should be inside the function.  That way it's accessible as `make_link.__doc__`, used among others by `help(make_link)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: No.  Dict of lists is slower for membership tests.  You can avoid the redundant 1 values by using a dict of [set](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s.

However, when working with graphs, there's frequently extra info we want to associate with nodes and edges ("labels", "coloring"). E.g. in your example you might store flight price or duration for each edge - it would naturally take the place of the 1s.

(This works well for directed graphs, where LAX->SAE and SAE->LAX prices are independent.  Undirected graphs are trickier to implement; a neat trick is a dict whose *keys* are 2-element [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s; but it might be simplest to duplicate data.)

Q2: No reason to, wasteful (most graphs have much less than n**2 edges) and is hard to maintain when dynamically adding/removing nodes.  You could use [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to *simulate* 0 wherever you haven't stored 1 (caveat: it'll *store* the 0s when accessed) but I recommend only looking at `node2 in graph[node1]` for connectivity checks, leaving `graph[node1][node2]` for extra edge data, if any.